# TCPDF footer image overlapping on main content

Tags: tcpdf

I am  using tc pdf library to generate pdf.
I have set custom hedar and footer  like below

```
class CustomTcpdf extends \TCPDF {

  public function Header() {
    $headerData = $this->getHeaderData();
    $this->writeHTML($headerData['string'], true, false, true, false, '');
  }

  public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-50);
    $image_file = 'footer.png';
    $this->Image($image_file, 15, 250, 183);
  }

}
```

Following  is the code for creation

```
 $tcpdf = new CustomTcpdf();
        $tcpdf->setHeaderData($ln = '', $lw = 0, $ht = '', $pdf_header_data, $tc = array(0, 0, 0), $lc = array(0, 0, 0));
          $tcpdf->AddPage('A4', 'Portrait');
          $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(60);
          //$tcpdf->setHeaderMargin(40);
          $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
 $tcpdf->SetY(70);
      $tcpdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, TRUE, '');

      $tcpdf->Output('HAKO.pdf', 'I');
```

output for  footer is as below 
[image]

Expected output is,
Instant of overlapping the content should come on next page.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following code in header function like below

```
class CustomTcpdf extends \TCPDF {

  public function Header() {
    $headerData = $this->getHeaderData();
    $this->writeHTML($headerData['string'], true, false, true, false, '');
    $this->SetTopMargin(70);
  }


}
```

With the help of  **this->SetTopMargin(70)** solve the header problem 
and for  footer   **$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 65);**  65 is margin from bottom  with this 2 mothod overlapping issue will be solve.